# POST form login credentials through redirect using wget

Tags: bash, wget

I am trying to use `bash` and `wget` to POST form data to a login page and save the cookies after logging in. However, I have to go through an indirect URL that takes me to the login page through two redirects.

I've tried a variety of other methods using `curl` and `wget` to no avail. They all reach the page, but don't actually *login*.

All of the StackOverflow questions and articles I've read on the subject claim it's as easy as the `wget` call below.

```bash
wget \
  --save-cookies cookies.txt \
  --keep-session-cookies \
  --post-data "username=$username&password=$password" \
  "$indirect_url"
```

Here is an example `wget` output:

```
--2021-07-09 15:57:21--  https://<<indirect.url.1>>/
Resolving <<indirect.url.1>> (<<indirect.url.1>>)... <<indirect.ip.1>>
Connecting to <<indirect.url.1>> (<<indirect.url.1>>)|<<indirect.ip.1>>|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://<<indirect.url.2>> [following]

--2021-07-09 15:57:22--  https://<<indirect.url.2>>
Reusing existing connection to <<indirect.url.2>>:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://<<login.url.2>> [following]

--2021-07-09 15:57:22--  https://<<login.url>>
Resolving <<login.url>> (<<login.url>>)... <<login.ip>>
Connecting to <<login.url>> (<<login.url>>)|<<login.ip>>|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                    [ <=>                               ]   6.32K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2021-07-09 15:57:22 (284 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [6473]
```

It seems to connect to the login page (200 response) and it downloads it, but it doesn't actually log me in, nor are the cookies.txt correct (e.g. no post-login cookies).

1. Are the credentials not getting carried through the redirect?
2. Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you.